# C# HttpClient tracing stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I want to log my request/response but I'm having a problem.
My request stuck at some point which I have no idea why.

Inside my controller I've this code

```
var log = new LoggingHandler();

using (var client = new HttpClient(log))// <-- problem here
{

    string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiBaseAddress"];
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    foreach (var website in websitesList)
    {
        string stringtime = TimeHandler.GetCurrentDateTime();

        var userModel = new RegisterModel()
        {
           // my user model
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
       {
              //encoding model
        });



        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/UserDetails/Register", content).Result;

            //tResult.URL = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.OriginalString;
            tResult.URL = website.URL;
            tResult.Result = response.ReasonPhrase;

            var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();

           .
           .
           .
           .
        }

        tResult.TestLog = log.GetLog();//*****

        resultList.Add(tResult);
    }
}
```

and my LoggingHandler

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public LoggingHandler()
        : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        sb.AppendLine("Request:");
        sb.AppendLine(request.ToString());
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        sb.AppendLine();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        sb.AppendLine("Response:");
        sb.AppendLine(response.ToString());
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        sb.AppendLine();

        return response;
    }

    public string GetLog()
    {
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

My debug stuck at:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Can someone please put some light and explain me why it's stuck?
Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Where is LoggingHandler.SendAsync called ? in ASP.Net there are some restrictions with the await/async pattern - I assume you have a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: I'm creating Log which is LoggingHandler type 
 var log = new LoggingHandler();
and Im creating httpclient(log)

Comment: I see that, but you are calling `PostAsync` in your controller, not `SendAsync`. And as Nkosi said, calling `.Result` (or any blocking method or property) on an awaitable method is very bad in ASP.Net and lead most of time to a deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous call when you use `.Result`.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/UserDetails/Register", content).Result;
```

That is what is causing deadlock.

Either go async all the way or not at all.

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/UserDetails/Register", content);
```

Comment: I changed my code line to yours but my function isn't an async 1, it's action result public ActionResult TestApiRegistration()

Comment: cant edit.
it's action result type method. 
should I change it to async method?

Comment: Yes. change to `async Task<ActionResult>` return type